# Prove true or false that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n}$ is absolutely convergent,

Tags: calculus

Prove true or false that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n}$ is absolutely convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{sin(a_n)*(a_n)}$ cannot be conditionally convergent

I saw a question in my textbook that asked this question and I wanted to see if I could solve it in preparation for my upcoming test.

I assumed it was true, an here is my proof.

My proof:

$(a_n)$ is absolutely convergent, which means $(a_n)$ is convergent;

So, $|sin(a_n)|\le$ $|(a_n)|$

(1) $|sin(a_n)*(a_n)|\le$ $|(a_n)*(a_n)|$ = |$(a_n)$|*$|(a_n)|$ = $(a_n)*(a_n)$

So, to prove that $(a_n)^2$ must converge absolutely, since $|a_n|$ converges absolutely, then $(|a_n|)$ ⟶0 for large $n$,  therefore there exists k>0 such that $∀ n∈N$$(|a_n|<k)$.

Thus $∀  n∈N$ $(|a_n|^2<k|an|)$.

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(k|a_n|)}$ converges, by Direct Comparison Test, ensues that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(|a_n|^2)}$ converges as well.

Thus, by Direct Comparison Test in (1), $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{|sin(a_n)*(a_n)|}$ must converge absolutely as well, and therefore cannot be conditionally convergent.

Is this right? Am I missing some important statements?
Much thanks.

Comment: Can't you just say $|\sin x| \le 1$?

Comment: @xaviermo2, that's what I thought of doing at first, but I read that $sin(t)\le$ $(t)$ for all $t$ is a stronger argument.

Comment: Well you could say $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent so $\sum |a_n|$ converges. Since $\forall x,|\sin x| \le 1$, $\forall n, |a_n \sin a_n| \le |a_n|$ so by the direct comparison test, $\sum |a_n \sin a_n|$ converges, i.e., $\sum a_n \sin a_n$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: I'd wholeheartedly support the use of $|\sin{x}| \leq 1$. Saves yourself a lot of effort!